# different way for private abstract constructor in java?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I had a class for a db connection like that (simplified):

```
public class SQL {

private static SQL instance = null;

private static String ADRESS;

private SQL() {
    try {
        // Settings
        settings = Settings.getInstance();
        ADDRESS = settings.getAdress;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ADRESS + "...");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public static SQL getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new SQL();
    }
    return instance;
}

public String select(...) {
    // SELECT Code
}

public String update(...) {
    // UPDATE Code
}

public String insert(...) {
    // INSERT Code
}

}
```

But now I need two variants of SQL and they mainly differ only in the settings (different databases). So I wanted to make SQL to an abstract class and overwrite only the constructor in the two inherited classes.
But as far as I could find out it's not possible to have an abstract private constructor!?
So how can I change the class SQL to an abstract class then?

Thanks, I hope someone understands the problen :)

Comment: Constructors cannot be `abstract`. That doesn't make sense. What you need is a `protected` ctor, not a `private` one.

Comment: Looks like you're paying the debt of misuse of singletons. It would have been better to have this `SQL` class by separate and a wrapper class that uses this `SQL` class and loads it with the respective values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
public static SQL getOrMakeInstance1() {
    if(instance1 == null) {
        instance1 = new SQL(pram11,param12,param13);
    }
    return instance1;
}


public static SQL getOrMakeInstance2() {
    if(instance2 == null) {
        instance2 = new SQL(pram21,param22,param23);
    }
    return instance2;
}
```

-maybe is a factory pattern, I don't know the names from design patterns :)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Best solution so far - avoids making the constructor public.

Comment: Ah ok, so I guess the solution to prevent the multiple instances for one database is the factory!? :)
Thats a nice solution! thx!

Comment: @user2170547 This also makes two instances when you call both methods.

Comment: ye I want one instance per database, so two in total is ok but not multiple per database...

Comment: @user2170547 This is what all here showed you actually. When you need another one, you create another one for some other db by calling new SQL(..). When you call with "new", you make an instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need more than 1 class.  What if you changed your class's constructor to take a `Settings` instance?

```
public SQL(Settings settings){
    ADDRESS = settings.getAddress();

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ADRESS + "...");
}
```

Then what you make different Setting instances

```
Settings settings = ...
SQL sql = new SQL(settings);

Settings differentSettings =...
SQL differentSql = new SQL(differentSettings);
```

Comment: Same as above.. can I prevent mutliple instances for the same database then?

Comment: That wasn't mentioned as a requirement in your original question.  You would have to keep track of what connections you have open or use somekind of connection pooling. That would all be done outside of this constructor